CVE handling for the linux kernel: looking for tool "dyad"
In https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bf3MYWtI4E4&t=1329s (about CVE handling for the linux kernel), Greg Kroah-Hartman mentions a tool / bash script called dyad to find vulnerable/fixed git ranges in the linux kernel repository. I am looking for this script.
In https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2024/q3/290, it is mentioned to be at ./scripts/dyad, but I cannot find it in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts. Am I looking in the correct repository?
Does anybody know where to find it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It’s in the security/vulns.git repository on kernel.org.
If you want the full repository (it’s small, currently just over 15 MiB), run
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/security/vulns.git

